# How to squirrel-proof trash cans?

Tags: outdoor

How do I find ways to prevent my trash cans from being tipped over by squirrels that try to chew over through the trash can lids? The bleach dries up.

I'd ideally like trash cans with auto-latching/auto-locking mechanisms that also act as rollers.

https://goo.gl/photos/FnWjB5UhHSoZ1KKo8

Comment: How big are your squirrels??

Comment: https://goo.gl/photos/FnWjB5UhHSoZ1KKo8

Comment: We have a ton of squirrels around here, but I've never had them try to get into our trash. Maybe get a squirrel feeder to appease them.

Answer (score 2):

Usual solution for racoons, who are stronger and more massive, is to bungee-cord the lids closed, and bungee the cans themselves to something stable (or sometimes to each other) so they can't be knocked over.

Picking a different design of trash can may help too.

Answer (score 2):

This might be overkill for squirrels, but in bear country, people use [Trash can sheds](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Leisure-Season-5-ft-2-in-x-2-ft-10-in-x-4-ft-Cypress-Horizontal-Refuse-Storage-Shed-RSS2001/203681871) to keep unwanted critters out:

[image]

Or, if your municipality allows you to supply your own trash can, you can get a heavy duty [bear proof trashcan](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DPJNA00) with a locking lid so even if it's tipped over, it won't spill:
[image]